# How to make JPanel scrollable in Java?

Tags: java, jpanel, scrollable

I have a class that extends `JPanel`, where I have overridden the `paintComponent(Graphics g)` method. However, I can't see the rectangles or the scroll bars I have drawn.

In the main function I have the following code below:

```
    MyClass mainPanel = new MyClass();
    mainPanel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(1000, 1000));
    mainPanel.setLayout(new BorderLayout());

    JPanel scrollPanel = new JPanel();
    scrollPanel.setSize(new Dimension(2000, 2000));       
    JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(scrollPanel,  JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS, JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);  //Let all scrollPanel has scroll bars
    scrollPane.setViewportView(scrollPanel);
    scrollPane.setOpaque(true);

    scrollPanel.revalidate();
    mainPanel.add(scrollPane);


    JFrame frame = new JFrame("Scrollable Panel");
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.add(mainPanel);
    frame.pack();
    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    frame.setVisible(true);
```

Comment: Have your read the [official guide](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/scrollpane.html)

Comment: Try `scrollPanel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(2000, 2000));`. Currently your `scrollPanel` is shrinking to nothing, so the `scrollPane` doesn't need to show any scrollbars.

Comment: @NimrodArgov, read his code, he has one.

Comment: When I change                                                                           scrollPanel.setSize(new Dimension(2000, 2000));                                                with scrollPanel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(2000, 2000)); scroll bars show up but the rectangles I draw through graphics object does not show up.

Comment: Official guide shows examples for attaching scroll bars to textArea or images, it doesn't mention about making JPanels scrollable.

Comment: @burcak There are no rectangles and graphics objects in the code you posted.

Comment: I have a paintComponent method in MyClass which extends JPanel, in this method I have calls such that .....                                                                                                                                                         public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {                                                                   g.drawChars(chrCharArray, 0, chrCharArray.length, top_left_x, top_left_y-10);                                                           g.fillRect(top_left_x, top_left_y + (low*enlargeFactor), width, height*enlargeFactor);
 
    }

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this issue. MyClass extends JPanel. And I  have overwritten paintComponent(Graphics g)  method in which I draw rectangles through Graphics.

```
MyClass mainPanel = new MyClass()
mainPanel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(7000, 1000));
mainPanel.setLayout(new BorderLayout());

JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(mainPanel, JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED, JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);  //Let all scrollPanel has scroll bars
scrollPane.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(1000, 900));


JFrame frame = new JFrame("Scrollable JPanel");
frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
frame.add(scrollPane);
frame.setSize(1000, 900);
frame.pack();
frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
frame.setVisible(true);
```